# My `qsort` program is not working as expected

Tags: c, qsort

I have some problems with the use of qsort. I've searched through different documentations, but don't see why my qsort is not working!

Here's the code:

```
char** suffixArray = makeSuffixArray(string, strlen(string));
qsort(*suffixArray, strlen(string) + 1, strlen(string) + 1, (int(*)(const void*, const void*))strcmp);
```

Notes:
makeSuffixArray makes an array of all the possible suffixes of the word "bananas".
Qsort then should sort these in lexicographical order.

The function makeSuffixArray does work, I've checked it over and over in the debugger.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Would like to post a picture of the suffixArray in debugger, but don't got the repuation for it :^).

Comment: passing `*suffixArray` is probably not the best idea

Comment: `strlen(string) + 1, strlen(string) + 1` Nope. The third argument of `qsort` should be (left as an exercise).

Comment: @Łukasz qsort's first argument is the adress of the element in your array, isn't it? If I pass suffixArray alone, qsort transforms it into garbage. And haccks, If I understand u right, strcmp is used for comparing two strings, I thought it worked well with qsort, have seen other people use it? Thanks guys.

Comment: @n.m. Oh should it be the size of ALL the elements together?

Comment: adress of the first element in your array is `suffixArray`, `*suffixArray` is address of first character of first element in array

Comment: [This `qsort` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) might be helpful.

Comment: @Łukasz suffixArray is a pointer to my array, it isn't the array itself. You can see it on the declaration (char** ...). Right?

Comment: `char*` is array of characters, i.e. a string, I asume you have an array of strings (that is `char**`) so `suffixArray` is a pointer to first element of array of strings.

Comment: "If I pass suffixArray alone, qsort transforms it into garbage". Perhaps this happens because of some other problem. Like, for example, `strlen(string) + 1, strlen(string) + 1`.

Comment: "suffixArray is a pointer to my array". Not exactly. It's a pointer to the first element of your array. You cannot pass "the array itself", arrays in C don't work like that. You always pass the pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: @Łukasz You're right! Thanks for convincing me, it got kind of confusing for me.

Comment: @n.m. Since the size of a character is 1 here, strlen(string) + 1 should be the maximum length of each individual suffix? The + 1 stands for the \0.
Am talking about the third argument here

Comment: It's fixed! Thanks guys.

Comment: The title is very misleading. `qsort` being part of the C99 standard *is working*. Your usage of it is wrong. But my point is that questioning `qsort` correctness is wrong.

Comment: The crucial question here is, what are the elements of your array? (Hint, they are not strings).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry! I will keep that in mind if I have further questions, I'm not that experienced on this forum. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not post the code for `makeSuffixArray()`.  Lets suppose it allocates an array of `char*` of length one more than the number of characters, since including the empty suffix, there are indeed one more possible suffixes than there are characters.

There are 3 problems with your code:

- You pass the first element of the array to `qsort` instead of a pointer to the string array itself.
- The array element size is `sizeof(*suffixArray)`.  You erroneously pass `strlen(string)+1` as the 3rd argument to `qsort`.
- Casting `strcmp` to a different prototype is not portable. Furthermore, the comparison function receives pointers to the array entries, not their values, thus `strcmp` is completely inappropriate.  You must define a specific function as follows.

Here is a modified version:

```
int scmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}

char **suffixArray = makeSuffixArray(string, strlen(string));

qsort(suffixArray, strlen(string) + 1, sizeof(*suffixArray), scmp);
```

Comment: It works! I understand it, made some dumb mistakes, first time working with qsort and did not find my mistakes. Thanks a lot!